# Manually generated DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn not updating bound object

Tags: .net, datagridview

When using DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = True, the boolean property of bound object is updated fine, but not when I add columns manually. Values remain False.

Are there some parameters I need to set when adding the DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn? It seems not to be sufficient to set the .DataPropertyName.

I see it has some other properties like .TrueValue, .FalseValue etc, but not sure what they are for?

Or do I need to write some type of custom CellFormatting/CellValidating events?

EDIT: 
I add column by extension method:

```
    <Extension()> _
Public Sub AddCheckBoxColumn(ByVal dgv As DataGridView, ByVal propertyName As String, ByVal colName As String, ByVal fillWeight As Integer)
    Dim col As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn(False)
    col.HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    col.HeaderText = colName
    col.Name = colName
    col.Width = fillWeight
    col.DataPropertyName = propertyName
    dgv.Columns.Add(col)
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show the markup and code behind if you add it manually in code behind?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the expression "code behind"? This is a Windows Forms project. But added some code above.

Comment: Do you run DataBind() on your grid after you added the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my mistake. Had an incomplete extension method with the same name in a different library. So it did not use the method I was changing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you misspelled the name of the bound field? It should work as long as your data column is of boolean type.

If not, TrueValue would express value to set when checkbox is checked, and FalseValue would express value when checkbox is not set, for example you could map strings "Checked" and "Unchecked" to field of type string.

1. Does reading from the field work correctly?
2. Can you check the checkbox, or It stays unchecked when you click it?

Comment: Yes I print the field in debug, and it always is False. Boxes are being checked/unchecked as expected. I'm definitely using the correct property name. So is .DataPropertyName only field that is required to set?

Comment: Yes, it is for the DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn. If you set value on object to True in code, does the DataGridView reflect that? Also try dataGridView.EndEdit() to commit user changes.

Comment: Ah.. Found my mistake. Had an incomplete extension method with the same name in a different library. So it did not use the method I was changing.